# How to pull value from jQuery plugin and set as PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery, variables, jquery-plugins

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Stepy](http://www.wbotelhos.com/stepy/), to allow users to complete a 10-step form.

Sample form: http://jsfiddle.net/wvkfn/

My site is setup so the user can leave the form in the middle of a 'step', in order to complete other tasks, and I'd like to have a variable set, so that when they complete the task, it takes them back to the last step they were on.

Is there a way to pull the value of the 'current' step from the plugin?  My first thought was that the plugin places a class called `current-step` on the title, and pull the number value from the title text that has that class set.

I'd then want to set that as a PHP variable, so I could set the task link to something like http://www.example.com/task.php?step=3.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'select' option stepy offers to register a callback when a tab is selected. In the callback use an asynchronous POST to your server to store the currently selected tab.

Sample:

```
$('#custom').stepy({
    ...,
    select: function(index){
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveCurrentStep?userID=1&step=" + index;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to store a `cookie` for current step OR you can use `anchors` for each step like for step 1 `mysite.com/task.php#tsep1` and pull the value from `URL`